# Can I use nested components linked with same app module? Is it good practise? Using component Router

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, components, router

Here is component structure of my application. Any advice will be valuable.  Root component is app.
 Which has two components as child : login & home.
 home has two child components : dummy-component & dummy-component1.
Is it good practice? Will I face any issue if I switch component router to ui-router. I am also planning to switch from angular 1.6.0 to 2.0

```
   App.component('app', {
        templateUrl: 'core/app',
        $routeConfig: [{
                path: '/core/teamnest/login-component/',
                name: 'LoginComponent',
                component: 'loginComponent',
                useAsDefault: true
            },
            {
                path: '/core/teamnest/home-component/...',
                name: 'HomeComponent',
                component: 'homeComponent'
            },

        ],
        controller: appController
    });




    App.component('homeComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'core/dashboard',
        $routeConfig: [{
                path: '/dummy-component',
                name: 'DummyComponent',
                component: 'dummyComponent',
                useAsDefault: true
            },
            {
                path: '/dummy-component1',
                name: 'DummyComponent1',
                component: 'dummyComponent1'
            }


        ],
        bindings: {
            $router: '<'
        },
        controller: homeController

    });


    App.component('dummyComponent', {

        templateUrl: 'core/dummy',
        controller: dummyController


    });

    App.component('dummyComponent1', {

        templateUrl: 'core/diff'




    });
```

Comment: Do you want to switch from angular 1.6 to 2.0 without code changes ?

Comment: There will be code changes. But will it be easy? If I structure my app like this using component router.

Comment: I guess it will be the same complexity. Anyway you will need to move functionality from controllers to components, refactor routes because router in angular 2 is different. Separation of components will only help to understand the structure

Comment: Isn't router in Angular 2 is based on component router? @NechiK

Comment: Ohh ... Sorry, I missed it. They are the same.